# How can I test jQuery using command line tools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, continuous-integration

I'm writing a javascript library that aimed for web applications.
Inside my library I use jQuery for cross-domain ajax requests.
I want to write command line tests to be used in my continues integration system.
Can you recommend on a testing framework that can do that?

Comment: Did you googled it?!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean.

Maby you search for this: http://terminal.jcubic.pl/

Comment: In fact, I try to do the exact opposite, I want to run the jQuery in server command line or developer machine while this tool enables executing command line inside a web application. I don't have a web application, just my library.